# Query buider Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table to store my articles. I have no pictures in this table, and my photos are in another table. I have added 5 posts and each post has 3 pictures. Now I want to get 5 posts and each post only takes 1 out of 3 pictures of it, how to do ?? i need help, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB3S3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e1a3.png)

Comment: Please consider sharing your codes..

Comment: $post = DB::table('posts')->join('images','posts.id','=','images.post_id')->select('posts.*','images.*')->where('posts.id','=','images.post_id')->limit(1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravel's relationship functions,
Add this to your Post model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(YourImageModel::class);
}
```

And for your query use this:

```
$post = Post::find($id)->with('images')->first();
$allImages = $post->images;
$firstImage = $post->images->first();
```

If you want all posts with images:

```
$posts = Post::with('images')->get();
```

In your blade:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->images->first() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: How can I get all posts, if I pass $ id then only one post will be retrieved, my data is displayed on the index page before $ id is passed! Thank you, if you can help me more

Comment: hello, my code  <img src="../images/anhhang/{{$po->image->first()}}"> I have obtained 2 posts, but my input path has not been named in the name field in the images table

Comment: can you update and share your post, image models, your controller, and view in your question?

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it, @ibrahim-dogan

Comment: Im glad to hear that! If it the answer was helpful and solved your problem please consider to mark it as solved and upvote :)

Comment: Hello bro, now I have another problem that I have an array of files [] and I use validate 'file' => 'required | image' then the elements in the bearing are not validated. @ibrahim-dogan